# Python Flask-Mysql KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask-mysql

I am building a python flask-Mysql app. I am building it using AWS cloud9. But When I run the code I am geting MYSQL_HOST key error.
I am attaching code below.
Is it because of the installation fault or code error.?`

```html
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


application = Flask(__name__)

application.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
application.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'nfhfjfn'
application.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'fsfc'
application.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'fsvf'
application.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql = MySQL(application)
# mysql.init_app(application)

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from LANGUAGES;")
    mysql.connection.commit()
    languages = cursor.fetchall()
    languages = [list(l) for l in languages]
    return render_template('index.html', languages=languages)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080, debug=True)
```

`

Comment: What is the full error message? Which line does it occur?

Comment: @Marcin 

this is the last line 
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 43, in connect
if current_app.config['MYSQL_HOST']:
KeyError: 'MYSQL_HOST'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `application = Flask(__name__)` **twice**. So second time you are overwriting the first `application`. It should be:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


application = Flask(__name__)

application.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
application.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'nfhfjfn'
application.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'fsfc'
application.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'fsvf'
application.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql = MySQL(application)
# mysql.init_app(application)

#application = Flask(__name__) <--- remove that

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from LANGUAGES;")
    mysql.connection.commit()
    languages = cursor.fetchall()
    languages = [list(l) for l in languages]
    return render_template('index.html', languages=languages)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080, debug=True)
```